# Intel MacBook Pro 2020 battery life much shorter than advertised

Tags: macbook-pro, battery

Ever since I updated to Big Sur, I've noticed my battery life on my intel MacBook Pro 2020 13 inch is quite poor. It lasts about 4 or 5 hours from full to 0 when I'm web browsing (I always use safari). This is far below the 10 or 11 hours or so reviewers seem to get on the device.
I got coconut battery so I know I'm 200 cycles in and the battery is at 87% capacity so it's not battery degradation.
I've reset SMC and PRAM multiple times to no avail.
I also can't find a good source of the drain, my activity monitor doesn't show any processes taking up huge CPU usage, I see no more than 20% use when I'm using Safari.

I have no idea what to do here, has anyone faced this problem and knows a solution??

Thanks

Comment: Do you like a bright screen? Backlit keyboard?

Comment: @SolarMike Hi Mike, I use the lowest backlight on the keyboard and usually run about 30 or 40% screen brightness.

Answer (score 1):

I'd recommend clicking on the battery icon in your menubar. This is a quick way to determine which applications or features are consuming the most battery.

Here's mine:

[image: Using significant energy]

Also, in addition to the CPU usage stats, Activity Monitor includes an "Energy" tab that includes columns for "Energy Impact" and "12 hr Power" that are worth investigating.

[image: Activity Monitor "Energy" tab]